# toolbar shrink with tabs in angular material show two scrollbars

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i'm doing a layout with angular material, and i having trouble when i use the `md-scroll-shrink` attribute of the `md-toolbar`.

I'm looking the code of this repo: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/7763 and i copied but in my page i'm looking two scrollbars

**The example is here:** https://github.com/corentin-gautier/material/tree/f7d9980fe4e61c7efa8bb31bf5505da930cc0b35/src/components/tabs/demoToolbarTabs

**My code is this:**

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <style>

        md-sidenav, 
        md-sidenav.md-locked-open, 
        md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active {
            min-width: 260px !important;
            max-width: 260px !important;
        }

        md-tabs-canvas {
            background-color: rgb(76,175,80);
        }

        md-tabs .md-tab {
            color: white;
        }

        md-tabs .md-tab.md-active{
            color: white;
        }

        md-tabs md-ink-bar {
            color: white;
            background: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>

    <div layout="row" flex layout-fill>
        <md-sidenav layout="column" 
            class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" 
            md-component-id="left" 
            md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
            <md-toolbar>
                <span>Toolbar</span>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-content layout="column" flex>

            </md-content>
        </md-sidenav>

        <div layout="column" ng-cloak layout-fill>
            <md-content>
            <div layout="column">
                <md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink>
                    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                        <md-button aria-label="back button" hide-gt-md class="md-icon-button">
                            <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
                            <md-icon>arrow_back</md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <h2>Toolbar & tabs with shrink</h2>
                    </div>
                </md-toolbar>
                <md-tabs layout-fill>
                    <md-tab
                    label="tab">
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
                        <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
                        <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
                        <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
                        <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
                        <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
                        <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
                        <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
                        <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
                    </div>
                    </md-tab>
                </md-tabs>
            </div>
            </md-content>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            angular.module('app', [
                'ngMaterial',

                'app.config'
            ]);

            angular.module('app.config', []);

            /*
            angular
                .module('app.config')
                .config(themeConfig);

            themeConfig.$inject = ['$mdThemingProvider'];
            function themeConfig($mdThemingProvider) {
                $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                    .primaryPalette('red')
                    .accentPallette('red');
            }
            */


            angular
                .module('app.config')
                .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
                            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                                .primaryPalette('green')
                                .accentPalette('green');
                        });


        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is: In the web page appears two scrollbar and shrink not work until the scroll of tabs is down.

If someone can help me.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan in the page appears with two scrollbars and shrink not work util the scrollbar of the tabs are in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of your content working as it should - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zBgOjd)

Here's an example of how I think you want it to work - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/GqVKbb?editors=1000)

[According to the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdToolbar), the `md-toolbar` must be a sibling of `md-content`:

[image]

so the shrink won't work with the `md-tabs` in your setup.

Markup

```
<md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Toolbar & tabs with shrink</h2>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-content id="myContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el
       ...
    </p>
<md-content>
```

Comment: then if i put the tab into a md-content why won't work? Also in the two codepen you dont have the shrink. Thanks everywhere.

Comment: @Arturo - The second (shrink) CodePen does work but you have to wait a couple of seconds before scrolling. This is the same with the demo https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar.